# Passing < > in xquery with BaseX POST method

Tags: xml, xquery, basex

I'm Using POST method to update BaseX database, I want to insert an xml node to an existing document calastone.xml in calastone database , if the node contains '<', it returns an error 
**" Line 6): The value of attribute "value" associated with an element type "variable" must not contain the '<' character."**

code:

```
<query>
<text>
    let $message := '<Id>CTN53</Id>'
     return insert nodes $message as last into doc("calastone/calastone.xml")
</text>
<variable name='message' value='<Id>CTN53</ID>'/>
</query>
```

the same code without '<' adds the text correctly.

how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angle brackets that occur in attributes and text nodes need to be escaped. For attributes, you should use `&lt;` and `&gt;`. For text nodes, CDATA sections are often more convenient:

```
<query>
  <text><![CDATA[
    let $message := '<Id>CTN53</Id>'
    return insert nodes $message as last into doc("calastone/calastone.xml")
  ]]></text>
  <variable name='message' value='&lt;Id&gt;CTN53&lt;/ID&gt;'/>
</query>
```

See e.g. [What characters do I need to escape in XML documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents) for more examples.

Comment: can you please suggest a solution to add xml node to an existing document in BaseX database with POST method? I tried CDATA but it gives same error. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have added some XML to my reply. – I guess that some more things will be necessary to finalize your task. The BaseX mailing list may be a better place to discuss further details.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I implemented the code but the solution isn't complete as you said, I have just added myself to BaseX mailing list. Thank you.